# How to transform one dataset into another recursively?

Tags: javascript

Given the following data, which I obtain from an api and which is occasionally modified

```
const data = [
  {
    name: "BG",
    latest: false,
    dir: true,
    etag: null,
    objectName: "BG",
    size: 0,
    lastModified: null,
    storageClass: null,
    versionId: null,
    childItems: [
      {
        etag: '"13dda89d102a62beb58c57a9477b252c"',
        objectName: "BG/item.xml",
        size: 12763,
        lastModified: "2020-11-17T13:13:34.735Z",
        storageClass: "STANDARD",
        versionId: null,
        childItems: null,
        name: "item.xml",
        latest: false,
        dir: false,
      },
      {
        etag: '"5baf1d6bcccc266bfc76cbe36724bd99"',
        objectName: "BG/item.xml",
        size: 17856,
        lastModified: "2020-11-17T13:13:25.796Z",
        storageClass: "STANDARD",
        versionId: null,
        childItems: null,
        name: "item.xml",
        latest: false,
        dir: false,
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    name: "OTHER",
    latest: false,
    dir: true,
    etag: null,
    objectName: "OTHER",
    size: 0,
    lastModified: null,
    storageClass: null,
    versionId: null,
    childItems: [
      {
        etag: '"ab37611f0b217b71804da19d9111bddd"',
        objectName: "OTHER/item.xml",
        size: 3953,
        lastModified: "2020-11-18T09:12:25.634Z",
        storageClass: "STANDARD",
        versionId: null,
        childItems: null,
        name: "item.xml",
        latest: false,
        dir: false,
      },
      {
        name: "MORE",
        latest: false,
        dir: true,
        etag: null,
        objectName: "OTHER/MORE/",
        size: 0,
        lastModified: null,
        storageClass: null,
        versionId: null,
        childItems: [
          {
            etag: '"aea98cd3b3aea692475c329d79c9e7aa"',
            objectName: "OTHER/MORE/item.backup",
            size: 573934,
            lastModified: "2020-11-18T09:45:08.986Z",
            storageClass: "STANDARD",
            versionId: null,
            childItems: null,
            name: "item.backup",
            latest: false,
            dir: false,
          },
          {
            etag: '"1a36b1f644f71a2f62f9c347da5fc381"',
            objectName: "OTHER/MORE/data.txt",
            size: 1045,
            lastModified: "2020-11-18T09:45:08.622Z",
            storageClass: "STANDARD",
            versionId: null,
            childItems: null,
            name: "data.txt",
            latest: false,
            dir: false,
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

I need to transform it to the following

```
[
  {
    label: "BG",
    children: [
      {
        label: "item.xml",
        data: "BG/item.xml",
      },
      {
        label: "item.xml",
        data: "BG/item.xml",
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    label: "OTHER",
    children: [
      {
        label: "item.xml",
        data: "OTHER/item.xml",
      },
      {
        label: "MORE",
        children: [
          {
            label: "item.backup",
            data: "OTHER/MORE/item.backup",
          },
          {
            label: "data.txt",
            data: "OTHER/MORE/data.txt",
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

The criterion is that when the `dir` property of an object is true, obtain the `name` and assign it to the `label` property, of the children in the `childItem` property, obtain the values of the `name` and `objectName` properties

It has been a difficult task for me to reason, I thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterate over the data items. For each item, get the label and check `dir`; If `true`, recurse to process the children, otherwise get the data.

```js
const processItems = items => items.map(item => {
    const results = {
      label: item.name,
    };
    if(item.dir) {
      results.children = processItems(item.childItems);
    }
    else {
      results.data = item.objectName;
    }
    return results;
};

const results = processItems(data);
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. I correct details in the code but right now I think I get the expected result